# JQuery looping .mouseenter animation does not stop

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm having trouble getting an animation to stop playing on jQuery `.mouseleave`, sometimes the animation stops and sometimes not, once it fails to stop it is unstoppable and does not respond to `.mouseleave` events. All other animations are fine, this one is the only one with a loop and is clearly wrong somewhere.

The IDs are dynamically assigned (Wordpress posts) so I'm referencing up the object hierarchy using `.parents('.someClassName:first')` and then down using `.find('findThisClass')`.

Can anyone see why it is not working? Or have a better suggestion how to do it. My code is...

```
// Call this function from below
function pulsate(myObject) {
    myObject
    .parents('.index-post:first') // Find closest parent
    .find('div.play-arrow') // Find child div to animate
    .css({
        visibility: "visible",
        opacity:0
    })
    .fadeTo(500, 1)
    .fadeTo(500, 0, function (){
            pulsate(myObject); // Loop the animation
        }
    );
}

jQuery("#index div.index-post") // The nearest parent with an ID  
.find("a") // Find the link
.mouseenter(function(){
    var $self=jQuery(this);
    pulsate($self); // Call function defined above
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(this)
    .parents('.index-post:first') // Find closest parent
    .find('div.play-arrow') // Find child div to animate
    .stop()
    .fadeTo(500, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Unfortunately the solutions above didn't work. I solved it by following  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368957/using-setinterval-in-jquerys-live-events-mouseover-mouseout). I need to tidy it up but the solution is below. I'm going to read up quickly on jQuery `.live` because it appears to hold the answer why nothing else worked.

```
// Play button animation
var timerID;
jQuery("#index div.index-post")
.find("a")
.live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    var self = jQuery(this);
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        self
        .parents('.index-post:first')
        .find('div.play-arrow')
        .css({
            visibility: "visible",
            opacity:0
        })
        .fadeTo(500, 1)
        .fadeTo(500, 0);
        timerID = setInterval(function() {
            self
            .parents('.index-post:first')
            .find('div.play-arrow')
            .fadeTo(500, 1)
            .fadeTo(500, 0);
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        self
        .parents('.index-post:first')
        .find('div.play-arrow')
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeTo(500, 0);
        clearInterval(timerID);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the animation on an  element but you try to stop the animation on the  element. Try calling stop directly instead:

```
.mouseleave(function(){
  jQuery(this)
    .stop()
    .parents('.index-post:first') // Find closest parent
    .find('div.play-arrow') // Find child div to animate
    .fadeTo(500, 0);
});
```

Comment: No luck with that either I'm afraid. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be in the pulsate method. The second call to fadeTo will start before the first call ends. I would put the second call as the callback event like this:

```
.fadeTo(500, 1,
.fadeTo(500, 0, function (){
        pulsate(myObject); // Loop the animation
    }
));
```

Comment: No luck with that I'm afraid. The problem is still there. I'm surprised something that should be so fundamental to animation, a loop, is proving so difficult to implement. It seems the core JQuery doesn't have a simple solution.